# LAST_INSERT_ID() with multiple records insert MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an sql multiple records INSERT, with an 'id' field set to AUTO_INCREMENT, something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (null, "bla"),(null, "bla"),(null, "bla"),(null, "bla") etc..;
```

and then i have another multiple records INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (null, "bla"),(null, "bla"),(null, "bla"),(null, "bla") etc..;
```

Now i want the 'id2' of table2 to be the same of table1, but i don't know how to remember all the last_insert_ids from table1 to insert them to table2, if i use LAST_INSERT_ID() it gives me only the 'id' of the first inserted value.
Does anyone know how to take all the last_insert_ids?

Comment: If you use auto increment you just need one ID plus the number of records you inserted to know all the IDs because you always increment by 1. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I am building this string queries dynamically and in the same loop, so i was wondering if there was a way to build both the queries in 1 loop, instead of 2.

Comment: my suggestion : each time you put last inserted id into array and when  finish it's use then overwrite with another insert id.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, indexes in your second table are references (like FK) to indexes in your first table.
In this case you could:

1. insert a record in first table
2. get last_insert_id() and store it in an array
3. loop 1-2 'til you're done
4. build an insert query using your array values

In PHP this would be something like:

```
var arrInserted = array();

foreach($newRecords as $newRecord) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 ($newRecord->valBlah);";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
 $stmt->execute();

 $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS myNewID;";
 $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
 arrInserted[] = $stmt->fetchColumn();
 }

if(count($arrInserted) > 0) {
 var $arrAddValues = array();
 foreach($arrInserted as $newID) 
   $arrAddValues[] = '(' . $newID . ',' $anyBlahValue . ')';
 $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2) VALUES " . implode(',', $arrAddValues) . ";";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
 $stmt->execute();
}
```

Ok, not so beautiful and *untested* but it should give you an idea...
Watch out for query size when imploding $arrAddValues, I believe MySQL has a limit and others may too.

HTH,
rash*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is that the "INSERT INTO table1 ();" is not a single insert, but a multiple records insert:
"INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (),(),(),(),(),();" and i want it to stay like this, because of the performace problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have multiple id's returned for the last insert id. MySQL works this way deliberately (See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)).

You should know your auto increment value (e.g. 1) so if you know you are inserting 5 rows, you would use the last insert id for the 1st row, and the `last insert id + 5` for the 5th row.

Comment: This is not true nor reliable. You can have IDs like `4,7,8,9,12,15`. `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not mean +1 in every case.

Comment: You set auto increment to increment by x for each new record. If you can explain a less hardcoded method, which does what the OP requested - feel free to post an answer.

Comment: And if one the record in the batch fails, it affects the entire batch causing a rollback and the `last_insert_id()` makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Ravinder correct. So either you use the method I suggested above, which is at risk of incorrect data (you can't just retrieve a list of the inserted id's using an alternative method) - or the structure of the insert is handled by individually inserting each row, grabbing the id, and handling any errors on a per-row basis. I'd choose the second option myself, but based on OP only being able to insert using the method in the question, I can't help further.

Comment: @Ryan In case of an error, would transactions make last_insert_id reliable?

Answer (score -1):

Try the simple way to use LAST_INSERT_ID() + number of inserts made (-1). If you're using native mysql auto increment, you should get a correct result.

If you're inserting the data in one transaction, the values should be in one row.

Look here how to solve you're question:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: This is not true nor reliable. You can have IDs like `4,7,8,9,12,15`. `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not mean +1 in every case. Even with transactions this is not reliable.

Comment: This is true for multiple index examples. And you could have problems if an engine reuse indexes.